# How Can I Create My Battleship Game Ship Setter in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating Battleship on Unity.I have ships, 4 species, different sizes board is grid 10x10, every element is image. I want to implement Drag&Drop such that when I take the ship it must follow the mouse position, when I release it on the grid, it must lie perfectly on the grid, and if I release it not on the grid it must take the initial position. I added to each ship 2dBoxCollider with perfect sizes to fit in grid

[Set your Boats Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOkmx.png)

[4Cell Ship with perfect fit on grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRPGn.png)

[Grid Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgLOr.png)

Collider 4 cell ship dimensions: 48.6, 11.4

Collider 3 cell ship dimensions: 36.2, 11.4

Collider 2 cell ship dimensions: 23.8, 11.4

Collider 1 cell ship dimensions: 11.4, 11.4
All Colliders offset = (0,-1.3)

How can i do the functionality, I know that I need ShipDragHandler butm but I don't know how to implement it. Also, my ships are in ShipContainer empty gameobject with VerticalLayoutGroup, which have 4 other empty GameObjects with HorizontalLayoutGroup

[Hierarchi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhYrX.png)

[ShipContainer Intspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT5X6.png)